# SQL Server : check if index exists takes a long time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL statement to drop an index if it exists.

When I run it in SSMS it is taking a long time

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM sys.indexes 
           WHERE object_id = object_id('Parties') 
             AND NAME ='Ix_Parties_Position')
    DROP INDEX Ix_Parties_Position ON Parties
```

Comment: Check to see what blocking is going on while you run that statement. You can get this info with something like this `select top 1000 r.session_id, r.blocking_session_id, r.wait_type, r.status, r.command
from sys.dm_exec_requests r`

Comment: Define "a long time". How big is the table, and how big is the index?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is large, it would be faster to get the object_id outside the SELECT statement.  If you have a lot of indexes, the object_id keeps getting evaluated for each index and this is not necessary.  Also, SELECT * is not necessary in an EXISTENCE check so using the number 1 eliminates returning all columns from the sys.indexes table.

```
DECLARE @ID int = object_id('Parties')

IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes
    WHERE object_id = @ID
      AND name = 'Ix_Parties_Position'
)

...
```